# How to search and replace multi line text AWK

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with following content  (snippet)  -- The test could be anywhere in the file.

```
More text here
Things-I-DO-NOT-NEED:
      name: "Orange"

      count: 8

      count: 10


Things-I-WANT:
      name: "Apple"

      count: 3

      count: 4

More text here
```

I would like to replace : (Including indentation)

```
Things-I-WANT:
      name: "Apple"

      count: 3

      count: 4
```

with

```
Things-I-WANT:
      name: "Banana"

      count: 7
```

Any suggestions on achieving it using awk/sed?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in `awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk

# Helper variable
{DEFAULT = 1}

# Matches a line that begins with an alphabet
/^[[:alpha:]]+/ { 
    # This matches "Things-I-WANT:"
    if ($0 == "Things-I-WANT:") {
        flag = 1
    }
    # Matches a line that begins with an alphabet and which is 
    # right after "Things-I-WANT:" block
    else if (flag == 1) {
        print "\tname: \"Banana\""
        print ""
        print "\tcount: 7"
        print ""
        flag = 0
    }
    # Matches any other line that begins with an alphabet
    else {
        flag = 0
    }

    print $0
    DEFAULT = 0
}

# If line does not begin with an alphabet, do this
DEFAULT {
    # Print any line that's not within "Things-I-WANT:" block
    if (flag == 0) {
        print $0
    }
}
```

You can run this in `bash` using:

```
$ awk -f test.awk test.txt
```

The output of this script will be:

```
More text here
Things-I-DO-NOT-NEED:
      name: "Orange"

      count: 8

      count: 10


Things-I-WANT:
    name: "Banana"

    count: 7

More text here
```

As you can see, the `Things-I-WANT:` block has been replaced.